# Fazer a câmera preencher toda a tela com Python/Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

Não estou enfrentando erros, porém ao acessar a câmera usando kivy, não sei como fazer para que a imagem ocupe o tamanho todo da janela. Abaixo está a parte do arquivo kv que faz isso:

```
<CapturarImagens>:

    orientation: 'vertical'
    Camera:
        id: camera
        resolution: (860, 600)
        play: True
```

Em "resolution: " tentei por (self.width, self.height) porém mostrou tela branca. Alguém sabe como devo fazer?

Answer (score 0):

Não sei o motivo de ter mostrado tela branca antes, porém agora ao usar:

```
Camera:
    resolution: (self.width, self.height)
```

Funcionou perfeitamente. Talvez eu tenha escrito errado e não percebi... O único porém é que isto mostra alguns erros como abaixo:

```
[ WARN:0] videoio(MSMF): OnReadSample() is called with error status: -1072873821
[ WARN:0] videoio(MSMF): async ReadSample() call is failed with error status: -1072873821
[ WARN:1] videoio(MSMF): OnReadSample() is called with error status: -1072873821
[ WARN:1] videoio(MSMF): async ReadSample() call is failed with error status: -1072873821
```

Ainda não sei se estes erros são preocupantes...